# How to pretty-print XML from SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, xml

Does SQL Server have a way to convert XML into nicely-formatted text, similar to PostgreSQL's `jsonb_pretty` function?

e.g. given XML data:

```xml
<Helpers><Thing name="Thing1"/><Thing name="Thing2"/></Helpers>
```

I would like text along these lines:

```xml
<Helpers>
    <Thing name="Thing1"/>
    <Thing name="Thing2"/>
</Helpers>
```

Comment: This smells like an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info). Formatting, the value nicely is a presentation layer "thing"; the application you're using should be consuming and formatting the XML "nicely" for you. For example, when you open `xml` data in SSMS, it formats it for human readability.

Comment: OK, then the question becomes, why does Microsoft's Azure Data Studio not have a built-in way to nicely present XML data rather than presenting it all on one line, and that's out of scope for StackOverflow. I was really hoping for a `jsonb_pretty` equivalent hiding just out of sight :D

Comment: You'll have to ask Microsoft. Azure Data Studio is a lot newer and is missing a _lot_ of the functionality found in SSMS. I wouldn't suggest it's a full replacement yet, and I don't think Microsoft would suggest that either.

Comment: Pass why doesn't do it out of the box, but I just installed [XML Tools 2.5.0](https://github.com/DotJoshJohnson/vscode-xml/releases) on ADS, and now it formats them automagically. There's almost *always* an extension for what you want/need.

Comment: Well don't that beat all. Thanks very much @ThomA, this is very helpful, I've got it working too. I still have a DB > ADS > .xlsx > humans pipeline where I'd rather the (paragraph-length) XML fields turn up legible, but having XML comprehensible while I'm spelunking is a huge boon by itself.

Comment: You can do anything with Powershell.  You can use Invoke-SQL to query database and get XML.  Then use any utility to process the XML including Pretty-Print.